# update in trigger causing recursive loop when call a function

Tags: oracle, recursion, triggers

I create a table that has a self relation like this :

create table Organization ( id , name , parent_id)

for easy access i add organization binary code to the table , and add a trigger for update the organization binary code after change the parent. 
when I want to update then i make recursive loop and take dead lock from oracle.

I update the code in a separate function and call it at the end of trigger;
 I make the loop like this:

1. Update The Record
2. Run The trigger
3. Update The Organization Code
4. Run The trigger
5. update The Organization Code
   and so on

Comment: Could you post the trigger code?

Comment: Why do you do this? `ELSE        :new.hierarchicode := :old.hierarchicode;`?

Comment: it's a mistake but the problem it's not for that

Comment: Ok, please edit your question including the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_Core_Organization_before
  before insert OR UPDATE on Core_Organization
 for each row

declare
-- local variables here
  parent_HIERARCHICODE number;
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

begin

  IF INSERTING OR (UPDATING AND :new.parentid != :old.parentid) OR
     (UPDATING AND :old.hierarchicode IS NULL) THEN
    Begin
      -- get last code in this root 

  --   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'ERROR HIERARCHICODE');

  select HIERARCHICODE
    into parent_HIERARCHICODE
    from Core_Organization cp
   where cp.id = :new.parentid;

  select NVL(max(HIERARCHICODE) + 1, parent_HIERARCHICODE || '001')
    into :new.hierarchicode
    from Core_Organization cp
   where cp.parentid = :new.parentid;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    :new.hierarchicode := cast(parent_HIERARCHICODE || '001' as number);
END;

  END IF;
end;
```